# Where can I customize the HTML invoice found in the customer's account page?

Tags: invoice, custom, html

I know there are extensions to modify the PDF invoices and packing lists. I'm assuming by PDF invoice, they mean the invoices that you can print from the order summary in the admin. However, when a customer goes to their account page in the Magento store they are provided with a link to a HTML version of the invoice. The customer's HTML invoice and the admin's PDF invoice look very different. My question is, where is the template or file located that I can customize the HTML invoice that the customer sees?

Or is there an extension to be able to customize the HTML invoice? I see a ton of extensions for modifying the PDF invoice, but I'd really like to modify the HTML invoice which is what the customer sees.

Answer (score 3):

The invoice template is `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/sales/order/invoice.phtml`.
the invoice items are rendered by `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/sales/order/invoice/items.phtml` and each item is rendered, depending on the type of the product associated to the item, by

- `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/sales/order/invoice/items/renderer/default.phtml` - for simple, configurable and virtual products
- `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/bundle/sales/order/invoice/items/renderer.phtml` - for bundle products
- `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/downloadable/sales/order/invoice/items/renderer/downloadable.phtml` - for downloadable products.

Comment: This definitely helps. But do you also know where I can change the layout of the HTML invoice? As in the look of it? I'm wanting to change the header where it has my logo and tiny address next to it and maybe add a footer.

Comment: do not miss the "print" : template/sales/order/print/invoice.phtml